# Delphi TDBGridEH image looks mirrored

Tags: image, delphi, mirror

I am using delphi XE3 with control from EhLib called TDBGridEH. The control is showing data and image directlly from SQL DB blob field. The image in the DB is OK but the image in the grid is mirrored. The control property BiDiMode is right to left this is the problem but is there any solution to fix the mirrored image?

Comment: I would personally report such behavior as a bug since RTL reading is for text, not for images. Maybe they have a property that explicitly renders specified columns in LTR reading but it shouldn't be applied to those rendering blob images by default, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself.

Fix ehlib file: DBAxisGridsEh
Look for procedure TCustomDBAxisGridEh.DrawGraphicCell and add the marked lines:

after:
      DrawPict := GetPictureForField(AxisBar);
put:
      if Self.BiDiMode = bdRightToLeft then
        Mirror(DrawPict, mtHorizontal);

Get mirror functiuon code from:
http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/f386.shtml

Comment: Would it be easier to stop the image being mirrored in the first place